# SSL Java Keycerts Certs

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

OK so keeping the code old as this is to run on Java 1.4 (don’t ask why) it's the only option. I need an encrypted socket connection between a client and server with Java 1.4.

The client and server both support common protocols and ciphers as can be seen from below.

I have run the code as is and the client fails with: 
IOException javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

The server fails with:
IOException javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

I have also tried to set the parameters in this case both client and server to SSL3 and SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA cipher. I get the same issues.

I imagine this is maybe keytool issue but how do you sign and connect to self 127.0.0.1

Thanks,

The Client Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts");
     try {
    SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket s = sf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 5000);            
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.println("some text");
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    s.close();            
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("IOException "+ex);
}
```

}

The Server Code:

```
public class SSLSocketServer extends Thread {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts");
    try {
        ServerSocketFactory ssf = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(5000);

        System.out.println("Ready...");
        while (true) {
            new SSLSocketServer(ss.accept()).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException "+ex);
    }}




private Socket sock;

public SSLSocketServer(Socket s) {
        sock = s;
}

public void run() {
try {
   System.out.println("In Run");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

  String data = br.readLine();
  pw.println(data);
  pw.close();
  sock.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("IOException "+ioe);
}}}
```

Client Supported:

> Supported Protocols: 
>   SSLv2Hello,  SSLv3,  TLSv1,  TLSv1.1,  TLSv1.2,
>
> Supported Cipher Suits:  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, 
>   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, 
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
>   SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,  SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, 
>   SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,  SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, 
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256,  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, 
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA,  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, 
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,  TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, 
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,  TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, 
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,  TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, 
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, 
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5,  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA,
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5,
>
> Set Protocols:  SSLv3,

Server Supported:

> Supported Cipher Suits:
>
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
>   SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5 TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
>
> Supported Protocols:  SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
>
> Set Protocols:  SSLv3

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're saying you need to use Java 1.4, yet you're visibly using a JRE 7 or 8, since it has support for TLS 1.2.

Comment: Have you set `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` anywhere?

Comment: This is not the real code. Somewhere you have called `setEnabledProtocols("SSLv3")`, and I would guess somewhere you have also called `setEnabledCipherSuites()`. Don't do either. Just let it negotiate. NB those truststore settings merely assert the default. You don't need that either.

Comment: Bruno, yes I am developing on a desktop which is up-to-date but the code needs to function on an older device. EJP - yes the example code above throws the errors stated and when I do add setEnabledProtocols() and setEnabledCipherSuites() there is no improvement.

Comment: You haven't answered @Bruno's second question. If you don't have a server-side KeyStore, nothing can work.

Comment: It was to do with the keystore not being implemented correctly

Comment: Not implemented at all as far as I can see. Unless you provide the solution you should delete this question.